# XMLHttpRequest can't sent unicode chararcter as request header

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I want to send an XMLHttpRequest via JavaScript and Everything work fine. But when i try to send a Persian string instead of English i got this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert string to ByteString because the character at index 0 has value 1587 which is greater than 255.
```

Note that this error just appear on Firefox and Chrome but everything work fine on IE.
This is a snippet of my code:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("serviceName", "سیبس"); // The line that cause of error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode the data into like base64 and decode it on server.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I solve that with uri encode and decoding. I think base64 will work too.